# Learning or Dedicating for Leilu Nishmas: Sephardic vs. Ashkenazic

Tags: minhag, names, torah-study, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

Just curious as to the differences between Sephardic/Mizrahi and Ashkenazic customs in regards to mentioning a deceased person's mother or father's name when dedicating something? I think Ashkenazim say the father's name and Sephardim, the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashkenazim always mentioned the father's name only.  (Except when praying for a sick person).

In more modern circles one can find Ashkenazim who will mention both parent's name.

By the Sefardim there are various customs (Sources: [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=766) and [here](http://www.hidabroot.org/question/92171) and [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/47973))

But when dedicating something one can write anything one wishes, pending local custom.